Overmuch vs too much
I'm wondering if I should learn the word overmuch. Apparently, there's no meaningful difference between overmuch and too much. So, is there any situation where you, as native speakers, would prefer to use overmuch? Maybe overmuch is more formal and hence better for academic writing?

To my ear, 'overmuch' sounds informal compared to too much. I (British English speaker) would never use it, it sounds like rural US dialect (it may not be, that's just the impression I get)

It's your choice.  "Too much" is the simple plain and formal option.  "Overmuch" is the fancy, slightly showing-off option.  The dictionary notes that "overmuch" is more often used in the negative, and sometimes in an ironic way "I don't have overmuch confidence" (suggesting ironically that I don't have any confidence at all)
I'd avoid it.

The word overmuch
is not very common
and does not have much currency.  The first three pages of listings in Google Books have just one publication from this century; the rest were mostly from the 19th century or earlier.
Google Books
Collins has a mention of formal:

[formal]
He was not a man who thought overmuch about clothes.

No similar mentions are found elsewhere.
This word may be more for negative statements; Cambridge says especially in negatives; Britannica says
usually used in negative statements.
